# Julia `remotecall` threads giving different results

Tags: multithreading, julia

While learning Julia from the [manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/parallel-computing/), I wanted to see if I could get Julia to run a hard computation on all four of my CPU's cores at once. I launched Julia with this command;

```
julia -p 4
```

Then I defined the following function, just for the purpose of doing a lot of arithmetic. The mod 13 is there so that it doesn't print a huge number in the end.

```
@everywhere function hard_computation()         
  bigexp = BigInt(999)^99999999
  bigexp % 13
end
```

Then I tell Julia to do this in four separate processes.

```
for i in 1:4
  push!(r, remotecall(i, hard_computation))
end
```

When I `fetch`ed the values in r, I got `[5, 6, 5, 5]`. I tried it several more times, and got; `5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7`. The correct answer is `5`.

So... what's going wrong?

System info;

- Julia 0.2.1
- Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (x86_64)
- Intel Core i5-2430M

Comment: Using the HEAD of GitHub's master branch, I can't repeat this on my wimpy and old 32-bit 2-core laptop.  All my answers (repeated 30 times) were 5.

Comment: If this is reproducible, it certainly seems like a bug. You may want to open an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm, everyone; turns out my RAM was corrupted.